# Mark or highlight files in Visual Studios Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, gallery, projects-and-solutions

is there an Add-In which allows me to tag or mark files in Visual Studio and then these files are visual highlighted (eg. different background color) ?

I searched the Visual Studio Gallery but didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Currently I revise an old project and want to mark the files I already checked/reworked so that I get an better overview. Sure, I could add a comment or something like that in the file, but I think the visual representation in the solution explorer is more straight forward.

Comment: Use a Versioning- and SourceControl-System like Team Foundation Server or Subversion. Using this you will see which files are modified and you write a comment when you check in the file to the versioning system.

Comment: Eventually you will have to commit your files, then you will need to open each file to see if its revised or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the extension [Visual Studio Tags](http://vstags.codeplex.com/) on codeplex that can do what we need, but there's not (yet) visual support (ie, diferent colors in solution explorer).

Answer (score 12):

To highlight only the active (open and viewed) item in the solution explorer (without any add-ins):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Projects And Solutions`

Then Check the `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` option.

But if you really want to use any extension in order to mark the files you already checked/reworked so that you get an better overview or whatever then I would suggest [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which has a number of features assisting [navigation and search](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html).

For example, there is a [To-do Explorer](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__To-do_Explorer.html) which helps navigation between to-do items within the solution. You can also [create custom filters in Resharper To-do Explorer](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2012/01/04/creating-custom-filters-in-resharper-to-do-explorer.aspx). After creating custom filters according to your need, you will have to leave comments wherever required but you won't have to open all the files to read the comments.

Comment: I think you are underestimating the problem. I got a solution with 2000+ itens to be revised and (sometimes) refactored. I don't have any order to follow, except what I think that makes sense at the time. Every day I think I spend over a hour (or more) opening and closing files because I can't mark then as "to be revised" or "revised", or "something else" in different colors in the solution explorer. What I can do (and what I'm doing) is leave big comments in the start of each file. Never the less, a big big mess. I have to open the file and read the comments every day.

Comment: I tried to look over ReSharper and I don't think it allows you to add custom colors to different itens in solution explorer.

Comment: @myself, May be I am not underestimating the problem. May be you are underestimating ReSharper. It has a To-do Explorer which helps navigate between to-do items within your solution. You can also create custom filters in Resharper To-do Explorer (for example, you may create "to be revised" filter). So, it's solving the navigation problem although it might not be a colorful solution as you wanted.

Comment: It's not exactly what I pictured, but it do the job. Best Wishes.
(each first line of the files now have to be revised and other sensitive filters and I can see then over the to do explorer).