# Highlight selected C/C++ file at the right place in other project in the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, filter, highlighting

I'm trying to understand a framework in C++, Visual studio by studying this framework's examples. All of such examples and framework are projects, and grouped in a solution in Visual Studio 2012. And each time, while reading an examples, I want to go into some classes the framework for more understanding and see where such classes located in filters in framework.

I searched in stackoverflow for highlighting filter in Visual Studio and I got two answers: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436222/how-to-locate-a-file-in-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906018/mark-or-highlight-files-in-visual-studios-solution-explorer).
   But my problem is I followed instructions in these two links, and they helped me highlight selected files, but they only highlight the selected file in the filter "External Dependencies". It do not highlight the source file at the right places, which is in other projects but in the same solution.
[image: external dependencies]
There's any way to do it?

Comment: Is right clicking on the identifier name and selecting "Go To Definition" or "Go To Declaration" not sufficient?

Comment: @ Captain Obvlious: Yes, but I want to locate what filter this file is located in, which would help me understand the framework's architecture better

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to examine the declaration or definition (implementation) of a particular type you can right click on the name and select "Go To Declaration" or "Go To Definition". If they are available Visual Studio will open the appropriate file and take you directly to the item you want to examine. It may display multiple choices (i.e. there are a few forward declarations of a type) that will allow you to select which one to view. As long as the source for the framework is in a project loaded in the solution this should be more than sufficient for your needs. If the framework doesn't have a Visual Studio project it's quite easy to create one and add the source files to it. Features like Intellisense, class browsing, etc. will be available for the framework and the project doesn't even have to build without errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know using "Go to Declaration" for going into the framework's class. The problem here is all the source files of framework are grouped into one folder in disk, while they are organized into filters in VS projects. Therefore, after I press F12 or "Go in to...", it's so difficult for  me to find out what filter this file is located in.